# Get function address from 64bit kernel32.dll using 32bit app

Tags: c++, winapi, 64-bit, 32-bit, getprocaddress

I have `32bit` application that running on `64bit` Windows (WOW64).
I need to know addresses of several `WinAPI` functions from `kernel32.dll`.

A can easily get address of functions in `32bit` `kernel32.dll`: `GetProcAddress` works well.

But Windows provide different `kernel32.dll` for `32bit` and `64bit` applications (or libs mapped to the different addresses in application address space - I do not know exactly).
And address of the `WinAPI` function in `32bit` app not the same as in `64bit` app.

How I can get addresses of the functions from `64bit` `kernel32.dll` using `32bit` app?
I do not want to launch separate `64bit` process just to know addresses of needed functions.

Comment: Start a separate 64 bit process and be done with it. Probably even that won't help you because you can't create a remote thread in a 64 bit process from a 32 bit process. I guess that's what you are wanting to do.

Comment: Thank you for help. I didn't knew that CreateRemoteThread always fails for x32->x64

Comment: You'll need a 64 bit injector come what may, so I think that's your answer

Comment: Yes, I got the same conclusion ))

Comment: The RVA (relative virtual address) of a symbol exported from a binary is a constant value, known at compile time. RVA + HINSTANCE of module == address (HINSTANCE is the same as HMODULE).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the question is meaningful.  Because of ASLR you can only ask "what is the address of the function when the DLL is loaded into my process(*)" and you can't load a 64-bit DLL into a 32-bit process.

(*) It may be the case that the answer is currently the same for every process run after a particular boot, but I bet the API supports a different address for `kernel32.dll` for each process.

(Also of course, the 64-bit value is likely to be much greater than will fit in a 32-bit pointer.)

Comment: kernel32 is not subject to ASLR. It has the same base address system wide: http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=198

Comment: Agreed, but my point was the GetProcAddress API (and similar) won't expose that detail.  The "same base address system wide" was what I was trying to say with "the same for every process run after a particular boot".